# Facebook post image not displaying

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want make a wall post on friend wall using facebook graph api.
Everything works good but image is displaying.
Here is my code.

```
 $attachment = array(
            'message' => $d['giftmsg'],
            'name' => 'You have received a gift voucher for ' . $dd['title'] . '!' . '',
            'link' => $plink,
            'description' => " Login to the Tippll facebook app to claim you gift card.   Your friends can click on the like above to top up this gift even further!",
            'picture' => $img_url,
            'actions' => array('name' => 'Top-Up This Gift', 'link' => $plink)
        );

  $post = $facebook->api('/' . $_POST['friend_id'] . '/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

Here $img_url contains the valid url and it shows image when i enter this url to browser address bar. But facebook is not fetching it to my post. 
I tried image from other servers and it works image hosted on other server but not in my server. 
I m using htaccess to redirect www to non www. 
Please suggest me the solution.
Thanx in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be 2 possibly reasons:

1. Your image cannot be accessed by facebook as facebook first get's your image and stores it on their cloud.
2. Your host is banned by Facebook and no longer accepts images from your URL's

Comment: Thanx @Mihai...This is my image.. https://www.tippll.com/welcome/deal_images/krishna.jpg
What may be the problem?

Comment: Can't you see SSL error. Facebook will not access it if you have errors.